# How to solve this error when verifying storage permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxw3Q.png)

```
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this
                , Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    _currentActivity,
                    PERMISSION_STORAGE,
                    MY_PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }
}
```

why does the first line have error the 2nd activity in the bracket is underline in red

Comment: my activity is called MainActivity.java

Comment: Post your error with image. We can't see anything from above code.

Comment: Post the code of the class in which you have defined this function

Comment: have added the picture

Comment: Still problem exists above code not give any error.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH how do i find the class?

Comment: @Choon Kai Wat do you mean i can't understand.